# Why join with subquery performs better

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have three tables;

```
Users -> id (indexed, big int)
Accounts -> uuid (varchar, indexed), user_id (indexed, big int)
Trades -> uuid (varchar, indexed), account_uuid (varchar, not indexed)
```

None of them defines foreign keys.

I would like to fetch Trades entries by user id.

I can get what i need with the following queries

Query 1:

```
select t.account_uuid
from trades t
inner join accounts acc on acc.uuid = t.account_uuid
inner join users u on acc.user_id = u.id
where u.id = 1;
```

takes ~4 secs.

Query 2:

```
select t.account_uuid
from trades t
where t.account_uuid in (select acc.uuid from accounts acc where acc.user_id = 1);
```

takes ~4 secs.

Query 3:

```
select t.account_uuid from trades t
inner join (
    select acc.uuid
    from accounts acc
    where acc.user_id = 1
    group by acc.uuid
) as acc on acc.uuid = t.account_uuid;
```

Takes ~1.3 secs.

I'm trying to reason about why the last query is faster compared to others? If i remove `group by acc.uuid` from the last query, it performs the same as others.

Comment: Did you compare the execution plans of the three queries?

Comment: We would similarly need the question to be edited with the execution plans added for us to be able to attempt a meaningful answer